# Calculating miles between two points using Vincenty formula

Tags: mysql

I have the following MySQL function:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `fn_vincenty_distance`$$
CREATE FUNCTION `fn_vincenty_distance` (
        lat1 FLOAT, lon1 FLOAT,
        lat2 FLOAT, lon2 FLOAT
     ) RETURNS FLOAT
    NO SQL
    DETERMINISTIC
    COMMENT 'Returns the distance in degrees on the
             Earth between two known points
             of latitude and longitude
             using the Vincenty formula
             from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance'
BEGIN
    RETURN  DEGREES(
    ATAN2(
      SQRT(
        POW(COS(RADIANS(lat2))*SIN(RADIANS(lon2-lon1)),2) +
        POW(COS(RADIANS(lat1))*SIN(RADIANS(lat2)) -
             (SIN(RADIANS(lat1))*COS(RADIANS(lat2)) *
              COS(RADIANS(lon2-lon1))) ,2)),
      SIN(RADIANS(lat1))*SIN(RADIANS(lat2)) +
      COS(RADIANS(lat1))*COS(RADIANS(lat2))*COS(RADIANS(lon2-lon1))));
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I cannot reproduce some of the airport distances in miles. I'm using `69.2 miles` as the distance between each degree of latitude at the equator:

**Case 1**

SFO-DFW

`fn_vincenty_distance(37.6188056, -122.3754167, 32.896800990, -97.038002010)*69.2`

Returns `1463.70` which is close to `1464.373` from https://www.airmilescalculator.com/distance/sfo-to-dfw/

***Case 2***

MIA-ORD

`fn_vincenty_distance(25.7953611, -80.2901158, 41.9745219, -87.9065972)*69.2`

Returns `1200.77` which is not close to `1197.062` from https://www.airmilescalculator.com/distance/mia-to-ord/

***Question***

How can I get the same answer being produced from airmilescalculator.com?

This is to match the calculation by airlines, for example from AA.com:

[image]

Comment: you need to work out your 69.2 miles for the correct latitude  see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/142326/calculating-longitude-length-in-miles

Comment: Do "qualifying" miles have any fixed relationship to actual miles?

Comment: I agree with Ian's statement. Your math aside, you're taking the 1197 miles from ORD to MIA as an authoritative fact from this random website. Without knowing how they calculated this value, I wouldn't compare it to real world math.

Comment: You are using the spherical case of the [Vicenty's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty%27s_formulae) , but the site seems to use the ellipsoidal method. Also, just multiply the `ATAN2` output times the radius of the sphere in miles.

Comment: @Mapperz the referenced question calculates at a single point -- how would I do this for two points?

Comment: @KHibma not trying to compare it to real-world math--I'm trying to compare it to airmilescalculator.com

Comment: @Kermit you should use the haversine formula https://www.igismap.com/haversine-formula-calculate-geographic-distance-earth/ as your using mysql you can do this https://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/stored-function-haversine-distance-computation/